# Neighbours list extracted out of polygon regions

Tags: sql, database, r, compiler-errors

I've got a SQL database which contains some coded polygon structures. Those can be extracted as follows

```
poly <- data.frame(sqldf("SELECT ST_astext(geometry) FROM table"))
```

The data.frame 'poly' contains strings that now can be converted to real 'SpatialPolygons' objects as follows (for the first string)

```
realWKT(poly[1,1])
```

I can do the previous for each string, and save it in a vector

```
list <- c()
for (i in 1:100){
   list <- c(list, readWKT(poly[i,1])
}
```

The last thing I want to do, is to create a neighbourhood list, based on all the SpatialPolygons by making use of the following function

```
poly2nb(list)
```

But sadly, this command results in the following error

```
Error: extends(class(pl), "SpatialPolygons") is not TRUE
```

I know that the problem has something to do with the classtype of the list, but I really don't see a way out.. Any help will be appreciated!

**Edit**

As suggested, some parts of the output. Keep in mind that the rows of 'poly' are really long strings of coordinates

```
> poly[1,1]
[1] "POLYGON((4.155976 50.78233,...,4.153225 50.76121,4.152384 50.761191,4.151878 50.761194,4.151319 50.761163,4.150872 50.761126))"

> poly[2,1]
[1] "POLYGON((5.139526 50.914059,...,5.140994 50.913612,5.156976 50.895945))"
```

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you provide at least the first couple of row of `poly`.

Comment: These are really long strings. I've put some parts in the edit.

Comment: Really? I don't see it??

Comment: It should be right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
list <- lapply(1:2,function(i)readWKT(poly[i,1],id=i))
sp   <- SpatialPolygons(lapply(list,function(sp)sp@polygons[[1]]))
library(spdep)
poly2nb(sp)
```

The internal structure of `SpatialPolygons` is rather complex. A `SpatialPolygons` object is a collection (list) of `Polygons` objects (which represent geographies), and each of these is a list of `Polygon` objects, which represent geometric shapes. So for example, a `SpatialPolygons` object that represents US states, has 50 or so `Polygons` objects (one for each state), and each of those can have multiple `Polygon` objects (if the state is not contiguous, e.g. has islands, etc.).

It looks like `poly2nb(...)` takes a ***single*** `SpatialPolygons` object and calculates neighborhood structure based on the contained list of `Polygons` objects. You were passing a ***list*** of `SpatialPolygons` objects.

So the challenge is to convert the result of your SQL query to a single `SpatialPolygons` object. `readWKT(...)` converts each row to a `SpatialPolygons` object, each of which contains exactly one `Polygons` object. So you have to extract those and re-assemble them into a single `SpatialPolygons` object. The line:

```
sp <- SpatialPolygons(lapply(list,function(sp)sp@polygons[[1]]))
```

does that. The line before:

```
list <- lapply(1:2,function(i)readWKT(poly[i,1],id=i))
```

replaces your `for (...)` loop and also adds a polygon id to each polygon, which is necessary for the call to `SpatialPolygons(...)`.